# Construção e Abstração de Classe

Tags: python, classes

estou desenvolvendo um pequeno projeto que cuida de organizar e controlar as vendas diárias de um vendedor do varejo. Basicamente o usuário irá imputar suas vendas e kpi's e a aplicação tratará de redefinir as metas de acordo com esses valores realizados, dentre outras funcionalidades, levando em consideração é claro, uma cota mensal.
Minha dificuldade nessa fase de testes é simular a passagem do tempo, pois muito da aplicabilidade do projeto está atrelada a isto (relatórios, feedbacks, etc). Decidi criar uma `class` TimeFlow, já que no paradigma procedural estava encontrando muitas limitações, necessidade do uso de arquivos, bem como falta de organização no código.

Segue código ainda no início:

```
class TimeFlow:

    ano = ('Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março',
           'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho',
           'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro',
           'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro')

    semana_completa = ('Segunda-Feira',
                       'Terça-Feira',
                       'Quarta-Feira',
                       'Quinta-Feira',
                       'Sexta-Feira',
                       'Sábado',
                       'Domingo')


    def __init__(self):

        self.dia = date.today().day
        self.mes = ano[date.today().month - 1]
        self.ano = date.today().year
        self.dia_semana = semana_completa[date.today().weekday() - 1]


def finaliza_dia(self):

        duracao_mes = úteis.dias_mes_atual()  # função que retorna número de dias do mês atual

        if dia == duracao_mes:
            pass
            # aplicar aqui def de passagem de mês
        else:
            self.dia += 1
            # preciso passar dia da semana também


def finaliza_mes(self):
        pass


def finaliza_ano(self):
        pass


def mostra_data(self):
        pass
```

Minha dúvida é como utilizar as variáveis que vão determinar a passagem de tempo e onde criá-las. Sei que o método `__init__` é executado toda vez que uma instância é gerada, logo faz sentido colocar essas variáveis ali, certo? O problema é que eu não estou conseguindo usar as estruturas ano e semana_completa dentro do método construtor, como podem ver. Ou eu poderia simplesmente criar essas variáveis como variáveis de classe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os atributos `ano` e `semana_completa` são [`variáveis de classe`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) e precisam ser acessados como tal:

```
class TimeFlow:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.mes = TimeFlow.ano[date.today().month - 1]
        self.dia_semana = TimeFlow.semana_completa[date.today().weekday() - 1]
        ...
```

Uma solução para o seu problema seria a implementação de um [`iterador`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterador) capaz de avançar os dias, os meses e os anos, cada um de forma independente, veja só:

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

class TimeFlow():

    dias_semana = ['Segunda-Feira','Terca-Feira','Quarta-Feira',
                   'Quinta-Feira','Sexta-Feira','Sabado','Domingo']

    meses_ano = ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Marco','Abril','Maio','Junho',
                 'Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro',
                 'Dezembro']

    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data if data else date.today()

    def proximo_dia(self):
        self.data = self.data + relativedelta(days=1)
        return self

    def proximo_mes(self):
        self.data = self.data.replace(day=1) + relativedelta(months=1)
        return self

    def proximo_ano(self):
        self.data = self.data.replace(day=1, month=1) + relativedelta(years=1)
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        dia_semana = TimeFlow.dias_semana[self.data.weekday()]
        nome_mes = TimeFlow.meses_ano[self.data.month-1]
        return self.data.strftime(f"{dia_semana}, %d de {nome_mes} de %Y")


t = TimeFlow(date(day=1,month=1,year=1970))

print(t)                 # 01/Jan/1970

print(t.proximo_dia())   # 02/Jan/1970
print(t.proximo_dia())   # 03/Jan/1970
print(t.proximo_dia())   # 04/Jan/1970

print(t.proximo_mes())   # 01/Fev/1970
print(t.proximo_mes())   # 01/Mar/1970
print(t.proximo_mes())   # 01/Abr/1970

print(t.proximo_ano())   # 01/Jan/1971
print(t.proximo_ano())   # 01/Jan/1972
print(t.proximo_ano())   # 01/Jan/1973
```

Saída:

```
Quinta-Feira, 01 de Janeiro de 1970
Sexta-Feira, 02 de Janeiro de 1970
Sabado, 03 de Janeiro de 1970
Domingo, 04 de Janeiro de 1970
Domingo, 01 de Fevereiro de 1970
Domingo, 01 de Marco de 1970
Quarta-Feira, 01 de Abril de 1970
Sexta-Feira, 01 de Janeiro de 1971
Sabado, 01 de Janeiro de 1972
Segunda-Feira, 01 de Janeiro de 1973
```

Comment: pode me explicar a utilização do método replace? O relativedelta já não faz esta alteração na data automaticamente? Usando o método proximo_mes como referência, se tivéssemos partido de 4 de Janeiro por exemplo ele retornaria 01/02/1970, não? No caso do projeto eu não terei necessidade de passar anos ou meses, a não ser que realmente seja o último dia do mês ou do ano, ou seja, o tempo passará naturalmente.

Comment: Um outra dúvida é que não estou conseguindo usar o módulo, está levantando excessão ModuleNotFoundError. Já fiz todas as tentativas possíveis e inclusive o pacote python-dateutil aparece na lista de módulos externos. O curioso é que a IDE também já reconhece os métodos auto-completando o código. Não sei o que pode estar havendo...